# DataTables warning: table id=DimStatus - Requested unknown parameter 'Code' for row 0, column 0,when initialize datatable

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, api, datatables

[image]I want to show my data in datatable but I get the above error.
My Table Property:

```
 [Table("DimStatus", Schema = "dmg")]
  public class PolicyState
   {
      [Key]
      public int Code { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
   }
```

My Api :
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class ReportController : Controller
{
private ICommonServices _CommonService;

```
    public ReportController(ICommonServices CommonService)
    {
        _CommonService = CommonService;

    }
     //  GET
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetPolicyState()
    {
        try
        {
            var draw = Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();
            var start = Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();
            var length = Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumn = Request.Form["columns[" + Request.Form["order[0] 
                                         [column]"].FirstOrDefault() +
                                          "][name]"].FirstOrDefault();
            var sortColumnDirection = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();
            var searchValue = Request.Form["search[value]"].FirstOrDefault();
            int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
            int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
            int recordsTotal = 0;
             var PolicyData = (from tempcustomer in _CommonService.GetPolicyState() select tempcustomer);
            //var PolicyData = _CommonService.GetPolicyState();

            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDirection)))
            {
                PolicyData = PolicyData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDirection);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
            {
                PolicyData = PolicyData.Where(m => m.Title.Contains(searchValue));

            }
            recordsTotal = PolicyData.Count();
            var data = PolicyData.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            var jsonData = new
            {
                draw = draw,
                recordsFiltered = recordsTotal,
                recordsTotal = recordsTotal,
                data = data
            };

            var testd = jsonData;
            return Ok(jsonData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

and last my index.cshtml:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<div class="container">
<br />
<div style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;">
    <table id="DimStatus" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap"
           width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>asdf</th>

               </tr>
           </thead>
       </table>
    </div>
</div>
 @section Scripts
  {
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" 
 src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            dataTable = $('#DimStatus').dataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            //searchDelay: 500,
            pageLength: 10,
            infoFiltered: true,
            orderMulti: false,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/api/Report/GetPolicyState",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },

            "columns": [
                { "data": "Code", "name": "Code", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Title", "name": "Title", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "render": function (data, row) {
                        return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteCustomer('" + 
               row.Code + "'); >Details</a>";
                    }

                },

                ]
        });
    });
```

would if anybody know the issue help me solve it. thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error clearly states that your returning data does not have any property name "Code". Make sure that the data structure your are returning contains property name "Code" as you are processing on **PolicyData** class and not **PolicyState** class that you have showed in the sample code.

Comment: Hi I have the Code in output. I put the image in my request

Comment: Issue is with row.Code in render line. I recommend, instead of rendering your HTML here, apply that as string in the back end mapped object as action property and then simply add in DataTables like a regular property.  Render does cause issues sometimes.

Comment: I delete that part  but I get the error .  and I cut the script part into js file in wwwroot but again the same error raise again

Comment: My Problem is solved and It refer to the Issue that I should not type the code in capital letter thank you for your help